# When receiving files over Apache HTTP Post, headers linger in file

Tags: java, apache, http, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am noticing that when I receive files in my Java app using the following libraries:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore-nio', version: '4.4.5'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.5'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.5.2'
```

I notice that the top of the file will have various headers such as this

```
--dVb9w156wIo3LdB-AjdoAEyD0yNsn9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="SendFile.html"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<!doctype html> <!-- now the actual file begins -->
```

I am sending using this builder

```
HttpEntity requestEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setLaxMode()     
        .setContentType(ContentType.TEXT_HTML).addBinaryBody("file", out).build();
```

So the headers should be in the `laxMode()` which is `HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE` and that actually does eleminate some headers from the file itself, but the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` still linger.

How do I ensure that I only write the body of the file when (on the client side) I write it out:

```
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tmp)) {
                e.writeTo(os);
                }
```

Some notes:

- The server and client are both Apache HTTP Java applicatnois
- I believe the issue is at the receiving end. My NodeJS Express client seems to remove these headers when I send files that NodeJS client.
- I would really rather not remove the headers manually, there ought to be a way to tell Apache to only `.writeTo()` body, not the whole thing.

Comment: Use another entity besides a multipart entity if you don't want the multipart encoding.

Comment: What entity will do the same thing I am trying for here, but leave out those headers? To be honest, I am leaning against changing the server because I know the Node client is able to strip away those headers. There must be a way for the Java client to strip them too.

Comment: Similar post https://stackoverflow.com/a/61486460/1162620